# WOPI Host OfficeOnline Word Error: Session expired

Tags: ms-wopi

Implementing office online in my application (php)...
Excel & powerpoint working like a charme!
If I want to edit a Word Document, I'll get "Session expired" in the editor view.

I've created a log file on my server...

date - request type - missmatch or "ok" - current lock string - request wopi-lock - old wopi lock

```
2017-06-08 14:35:00 - CheckFileInfo -- Current Lock:  || X-Wopi-Lock:  || X-Wopi-OldLock: 
2017-06-08 14:35:01 - Lock - OK -- Current Lock:  || X-Wopi-Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":4} || X-Wopi-OldLock: 
2017-06-08 14:35:01 - GetFile -- Current Lock:  || X-Wopi-Lock:  || X-Wopi-OldLock: 
2017-06-08 14:35:01 - Lock - Missmatch -- Current Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":4} || X-Wopi-Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":6,"E":2,"M":"2e113d2cc5e0457f94543c383961bd37","P":"3823A714-066D-4B80-9D32-439DA70147B0"} || X-Wopi-OldLock: 
2017-06-08 14:35:01 - Lock - Missmatch -- Current Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":4} || X-Wopi-Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":6,"E":2,"M":"2e113d2cc5e0457f94543c383961bd37","P":"3823A714-066D-4B80-9D32-439DA70147B0"} || X-Wopi-OldLock: 
2017-06-08 14:35:01 - Lock - Missmatch -- Current Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":4} || X-Wopi-Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":6,"E":2,"M":"2e113d2cc5e0457f94543c383961bd37","P":"3823A714-066D-4B80-9D32-439DA70147B0"} || X-Wopi-OldLock: 
2017-06-08 14:35:05 - Unlock - Missmatch -- Current Lock: {"S":"fdcc8cdd-1173-4935-b94b-aca35228a332","F":4} || X-Wopi-Lock: GetCurrentLock-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 || X-Wopi-OldLock:
```

If I "haked" a 200 response in the "missmatch", the session expired is gone :P 
But then, I've no Co-Authoring.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out! I didn't get the OldLock header as espected beacause it is case sensetive in the header array..

changed `$headers['X-Wopi-OldLock']` to `$headers['X-Wopi-Oldlock']` and now I'm back in business!

thanks